# Android LruCache OutOfMemoryException

Tags: android, bitmap

I was doing an android application with a lot of pictures, when I load many pictures in memory,  OutOfMemoryException occurs.

I search the project with google , and most of webpages recommend to use bitmap.recycle() and LruCache, but what I fell puzzled is that when I remove bitmap from LruCache, the removed bitmap still take up memory,how does LruCache reduce memory usage ??

Answer (score 1):

> how does LruCache reduce memory usage ??

`LruCache` dose not reduce memory usage, it just decreases your loading time and removes unnecessary download or decode operations. if you can not manage your `bitmap` size and decode it correctly you will get `OOM` exception even if you are using `LruCache`.

Comment: I want to load a lot of bitmap to cache(memory), but my phone(mb525) limits app heap size  48M , some of my picture needs to be loaded in  cache, I use bitmap.recycle to reduce memory usage after I look other pictures,but the method of recycle() does not notify system to execute gc right now , the app heap usage size still up. What I can do to solve OutOfMemory? Thanks.

Comment: Read [Loading Large Bitmaps Efficiently](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html).

Answer (score 0):

> when I remove bitmap from LruCache, the removed bitmap still take up memory

Only until it is garbage-collected. If nothing else besides your cache is holding onto the bitmap, once you remove it from the cache, it can get garbage-collected, and that should be done before your next `OutOfMemoryError`.

Comment: But What I can do to execute  garbage-collected manually when I remove bitmap from cache ?

Comment: @Honest: You do not need to "execute garbage-collected manually when I remove bitmap from cache". A full GC will occur before an `OutOfMemoryError` is thrown.

Answer (score 0):

Based on an Google Devs videos, we have to find the best size for our cache. Which can be done by the code below:

```
     ActivityManager am= (ActivityManager) context.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    diskCacheSize = (am.getMemoryClass()*1024*1024)/8;
```

Please let me add this official Google video about LRU cache.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R5ON3iwx78M

This video says, the cache manage itself, by removing objects from the end of the queue, so you don`t need to do it by your self.

Do you using the option parameters when loading bitmaps ? You can save a lot of space by reducing the size of the image and the quality as well.